# Tomcat server main page not appearing when i'm launching tomcat web app through azure

Tags: azure, tomcat, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to create tomcat server using web app in azure . But browsing URL is showing JAVA page not tomcat home page .

When i debugged using DebugConsole ,i'm unable to find any tomcat configuration files.

I'm using free tier .

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your app in the Azure Portal, then navigate to the *Configuration -> General Settings* blade and select *Tomcat* in the *Java container* drop-down. That should configure your app to use Tomcat. Check the screenshot for more clarity.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, here we have our quickstarts:

Tomcat Web App on App Service (Windows):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-java

Tomcat Web App on App Service (Linux):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-java